# Transaction commit is missing in Spring Integration MessageHandler (sometimes)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I use spring integration. A poller asks a MessageSource that receive files from filesystem  and a MessageHandler shall write content (from file) to database.

No problems with poller or MessageSource, but the database entry is not persisted (code follows) even when the logs show no errors and the handling is done without problems.

What drives me nuts is that I use the same logic at another place without problems.

Sorry for the german/english mix. I will polish the code further for easier reading.

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource<File> messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private DbMessageHandler handlerDb;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel fileChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "${poller.fixedDelay}"))
    public Message<File> retrieveMessage() {
        return messageSource.receive();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileChannel")
    public void handle(Message<File> message) {
        handlerDb.handleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

The MessageHandler:

```
@Component
public class DbMessageHandler extends AbstractBzstDateiMessageHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbMessageHandler.class);

    private final MessageHandler antwortenAsyncHandler;
    private final MessageHandler antwortenVerarbeitetHandler;
    private final AntwortAnnahmeService antwortAnnahmeService;

    public DbMessageHandler(BzstAccount account, AntwortAnnahmeService antwortAnnahmeService,
            MessageHandler antwortenAsyncHandler, MessageHandler antwortenVerarbeitetHandler, BeanFactory beanFactory,
            EncryptService encryptService) {
        super(account, beanFactory, encryptService);
        this.antwortenAsyncHandler = antwortenAsyncHandler;
        this.antwortenVerarbeitetHandler = antwortenVerarbeitetHandler;
        this.antwortAnnahmeService = antwortAnnahmeService;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        if (Objects.isNull(message) || !(message.getPayload() instanceof File)) {
            throw new MessagingException(message,
                    "Null als Nachricht/Payload oder eine Payload die keine Datei ist, kann nicht verarbeitet werden.");
        }
        BzstDatei datei = createBzstDatei(message, false); //Creates DTO from file. No DB involved.

        LOG.info("Speichere Antwort vom Amt {} in die Datenbank.", datei.getDateiNameKomplett());
        try {
            antwortAnnahmeService.annahmeAntwort(datei); //Here I dive into service layer
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MessagingException(message, "Antwort konnte nicht in der Datenbank gespeichert werden.", e);
        }
        if (!antwortAnnahmeService.isAntwortAngenommen(datei.getDateiNameKomplett())) {
            //Here I double check if it is in database.
            throw new MessagingException(message, "Die Antwort konnte nicht persistiert werden!");
        }
        LOG.info("Leite Antwort vom Amt {} zum Async Handler zur Nachberarbeitung weiter.",
                datei.getDateiNameKomplett());

        try {
            antwortenAsyncHandler.handleMessage(message);
            antwortenVerarbeitetHandler.handleMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Antwort konnte nicht asynchron bereit gestellt werden.", e);
        } finally {
            deleteLocalFile(message);
        }
    }

}
```

The First Service:

```
@Service
@Validated
public class AntwortAnnahmeService {

    private final DateiService dateiService;

    @Autowired
    public AntwortAnnahmeService(DateiService dateiService) {
        super();
        this.dateiService = dateiService;
    }

    public BzstDatei annahmeAntwort(@Valid @NotNull BzstDatei datei) {
        // Persistieren
        return dateiService.speichereAntwort(datei);
    }

    public boolean isAntwortAngenommen(String dateiName) {
        return dateiService.isAntwortAngenommen(dateiName);
    }
}
```

The second service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DateiService {

    @Autowired
    private DateiRepository dateiRepo;
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accService;
    @Autowired
    private DateiMapper dateiMapper;

    public boolean isAntwortAngenommen(String dateiName) {
        return dateiRepo.findByNameAndTyp(dateiName, DateiTypE.ANTWORT_VOM_AMT).isPresent();
    }

    public BzstDatei speichereAntwort(BzstDatei datei) {
        return erstelle(datei, DateiTypE.ANTWORT_VOM_AMT);
    }

    private BzstDatei erstelle(BzstDatei datei, DateiTypE typ) {
        Account account = accService.getAccountIntern(datei.getBzstAccount());

        Datei jpaDatei = new Datei();
        DateiInhalt inhalt = new DateiInhalt();
        inhalt.setInhalt(datei.getInhalt());
        jpaDatei.setInhalt(inhalt);
        jpaDatei.setName(datei.getDateiNameKomplett());
        jpaDatei.setTyp(typ);
        jpaDatei.setEingang(LocalDate.now());
        jpaDatei.setAccount(account);
        try {
            return dateiMapper.dateiToBzstDatei(dateiRepo.saveAndFlush(jpaDatei));
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (dateiRepo.findByNameAndTyp(jpaDatei.getName(), typ).isPresent()) {
                throw new DataAlreadyExistsException("Datensatz ist schon vorhanden.");
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the MessageHandler calls the service layer to persist entry. In service layer is @Transactional.
The Handler finishes without problems. Here an example log (sorry german):

```
2022-08-04 09:12:31.865  INFO 10128 --- [   scheduling-1] d.v.l.v.b.c.DbMessageHandler             : Speichere Antwort vom Amt AntwortAnnahmeAsynchronIntegrationTest.txt in die Datenbank.
2022-08-04 09:12:32.040  INFO 10128 --- [   scheduling-1] d.v.l.v.b.c.DbMessageHandler             : Leite Antwort vom Amt AntwortAnnahmeAsynchronIntegrationTest.txt zum Async Handler zur Nachberarbeitung weiter.
2022-08-04 09:12:32.087  INFO 10128 --- [   scheduling-1] .l.v.b.c.AbstractBzstDateiMessageHandler : Lösche src\test\resources\AntwortAnnahmeAsynchronIntegrationTest.txt.
```

It shows that the code lines after the save operation are executed. No errors are thrown.
When I ask inside the MessageHandler after the save operation in another transaction the entry is found, but when I do a SpringBootTest and ask there if something is in the database the test fails (most times - in normal execution; In debug mode it passes).

Here the SpringBootTest:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, value = {
        "spring.config.additional-location=./src/test/resources/entwicklertest_h2.properties" })
class AntwortAnnahmeAsynchronIntegrationTest extends AbstractBzstIntegrationTest {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "...";

    @Autowired
    private DateiService dateiService;

    @Autowired
    private DateiRepository dateiRepository;

    @Test
    void contextLaden() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        dateiRepository.deleteAll();
        Assertions.assertFalse(dateiService.isAntwortAngenommen(FILE_NAME));
        Message<File> message = createMessage();
        Mockito.when(messageSource.receive()).thenReturn(message, (Message<File>) null);
        boolean processed = false;
        LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        while (LocalDateTime.now().minus(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).isBefore(startTime)) {
            try {
                Mockito.verify(messageSource).receive();
                processed = true;
                break;
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                // Weiter warten.
            }
        }
        Assertions.assertTrue(processed);
        startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        while (LocalDateTime.now().minus(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).isBefore(startTime)) {
            try {
                Assertions.assertTrue(dateiService.isAntwortAngenommen(FILE_NAME));
                break;
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                // Weiter warten.
            }
        }
        Assertions.assertTrue(dateiService.isAntwortAngenommen(FILE_NAME)); //<-. fails here
    }
```

It doesn't matter if I wait 10 seconds or 30 days.

I use spring-boot-parent 2.7.1

Any help is appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Update:
I added two further tests.

```
@Test
    @Order(2)
    void verifyFinalDatabaseStateWithCount() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, dateiRepository.count());
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void verifyFinalDatabaseStateWithName() {
   
   
  Assertions.assertTrue(dateiService.isAntwortAngenommen(FILE_NAME));
    }
```

I cannot explain the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN6Cb.png)

Comment: What does your `createMessage` look like? Finally you are, apparently,m return `null` from the `MessageSource.receive()` call. So I would expect that there is nothing to interpret in the first place and something randomg is being added to the database and nothing related to your `FILE_NAME` property.

Comment: GenericMessage [payload=src\test\resources\AntwortAnnahmeAsynchronIntegrationTest_1fa4a729-8057-4b68-9210-6c866deb0ca1.txt, headers={id=b3773563-b982-df03-e019-f701e3685b9d, timestamp=1659610561376}]
Since I get the LOG lines after throw new MessageException I think null is not the problem.